# Pandas groupby - Apply circular mean to aggregate 10-minutely data into hourly data - Faster?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, vectorization, apply, circular-dependency

I need your help in elaborating a faster way of grouping 10-minutely angular/circular data. Since circular data ranges from 0 to 360, the ordinary mean does not capture the relation between 0 and 360. Therefore, I want to use scipy.stats circmean to accomplish circular mean values. I already figured that the apply() method implemented in pd.groupby is very slow (120s for standard lenovo laptop machine) in resembling 10-minutely data to hourly groups and then applying the circular mean on these groups.

Furthermore, the dataset I am using can consist of non-consecutive timestamps. Nevertheless, is there a way of speeding up the following code (e.g. by vectorization)?

Many thanks in advance for your help. Let me know, if you need more information on this.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import circmean

data = pd.DataFrame()
start = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
data['time'] = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='10T')
data['angles'] = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=360.0, size=(len(data.time),))
data.drop(data.index[1500:2000], inplace=True)

def mean2(df):
    '''
    :param df: 10min Values inside a dataframe for the according hour - DataFrame
    :return: df_out: The aggregated dataframe - DataFrame
    '''
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    try:
        df_out.at[0,'angles'] = round(np.rad2deg(circmean(np.deg2rad(df['angles']))),2)
        df_out.at[0, 'time'] = df.time.iloc[0]
        df_out.time = pd.to_datetime(df_out.time)
        return df_out

    except:
        return df_out

start_time = time.time()
data_hourly = data.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='time',freq='1H')], as_index=False).apply(mean2)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Please indicate an input with expected output in addition to the full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of useless stuff happening in your `mean2` function.

When a function is applied to a `groupby`, pandas will automatically recreate a new dataframe, there is no need to do some weird column / index accessing in your function. Moreover, it is really expensive for pandas to access data at a specific column / index pair (the `at` method).

Below a simplistic approach that is more efficient:

```py
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import circmean

data = pd.DataFrame()
start = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
data['time'] = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='10T')

data['angles'] = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=360.0, size=(len(data.time),))
data.drop(data.index[1500:2000], inplace=True)

def circular_mean(x):
    return round(np.rad2deg(circmean(np.deg2rad(x['angles'].values))),2)

start_time = time.time()
data.index = data['time']
data_hourly = data.resample(rule='1H').apply(circular_mean)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```